# extract 7z extension - PHP

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am wondering if PHP can extract the *.7z extension. I have searched a lot about it and I all what I see is *.zip, *.rar etc... but not 7z. Here is the code that I have tried. `ZipArchive();` is not supporting 7z.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x = $zip->open($target_path); //I have tried ,ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE after path but no luck.

if($x === true) {
  $zip->extractTo('../uploads/ext');
  $zip->close();

  echo "Your zip file has been unpacked.";
}
else
{
  echo 'not unpacked!';
}
```

I have many 7z files and I am looking to let PHP unpack them to get information from them. I have looked at 7zip website for some resources but no luck. Its looks like `ZipArchive();` cannot open *.7z

Does anyone have any idea about this?

I need to unzip 7z extension by PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to extract 7z extension you will need some kind of library, because ZipArchive() function is only for .zip archives.

To extract .7z you can use for example this library (Wrapper 7-zip (p7zip)):
https://github.com/Gemorroj/Archive7z

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to run 7z

```
$filesToIncludeZip[] = "{$pathToExtract}/{$directory}/Add.txt";
$aux = implode(' ', $filesToIncludeZip);
$strCommandLine = "7z a {$pathToExtract}/{$directory}/new.zip {$aux} -y -tZIP";

exec($strCommandLine, $out1, $return_var_into);
```